# VB .NET: cannot get proper response after HTTP POST

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to return the HTML from this search result, but all I am able to get is the original page with the value inserted into the appropriate textbox.  This code apparently works for other people and I am not sure what the problem is.

```
 ' Create a new WebClient instance. 
 Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
 myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4")

 ' Create a new NameValueCollection instance to hold some custom parameters to be posted to the URL. 
 Dim myNameValueCollection As New NameValueCollection()

 ' Add necessary parameter/value pairs to the name/value container.
 myNameValueCollection.Add("conCSLB", "619412")

 ' The Upload(String,NameValueCollection)' method implicitly sets the HTTP POST as the request method.
 Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadValues("https://efiling.dir.ca.gov/PWCR/Search", myNameValueCollection)

 ' Decode and display the response.
 Dim response As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the search result page? And sending the submit button information?

Comment: I believe so, but this is part of why I am asking the question - to find out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the server side script checks for the presence of the other 2 input elements, even if they are empty. Add them:

```
myNameValueCollection.Add("regNumber", "")
myNameValueCollection.Add("legalName", "")
```

This solves your main problem, now you need to parse the HTML. But I found an interesting thing: you can just download the XLS and parse that:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://efiling.dir.ca.gov/PWCR/Search.action?6578706f7274=1&legalName=&conCSLB=619412&regNumber=&d-49653-e=2", "output.txt")
```

This file contains raw data (not real XLS!):

```
"Legal Name"    "Registration Number"   "License Type/Number(s)"            "Registration Date" "Expiration Date"
"BLASER BUILDING SPECIALTIES, INC." "1000006374"    "CSLB:619412"   "01/21/2015"    "06/30/2015"
```

Just change the parameter in the URL and you're done

Comment: Spot on!  I have been pulling my hair out for a few hours trying to figure this out.  I can't believe it was so simple.